# UICollectionView paging and swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking if four directions is possible with the swipe.

Can I get some example code 
like this app: [LINK](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vessel-early-access-to-your/id943718088?mt=8)

or any idea?

I am making this controller use **UICollectionview**.

Comment: could u please elaborate it..? u mean u r using UICollection View ..in that every image should be swipe..am i right??

Comment: @vanilucky i want show fullsize image and swipe 4way.with array

Comment: @realmasse I'm no expert but I think you need programming for that. :) No, but for real, welcome to StackOverflow and read up on the [guidelines for asking a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as this one is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [secCollectionImagesArray count];

NSLog(@"secCollectionimagesArray is:%@ ",secCollectionImagesArray);

}
- (MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
UILabel *descLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:110];

[descLabel setText:[secCollectionImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[secCollectionImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

int pages = floor(collectionView.contentSize.width / collectionView.frame.size.width) + 1;
[pageControl setNumberOfPages:pages];

return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

third=[[thirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"thirdViewController" bundle:nil];

third.recipeImagedname=[secCollectionImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self presentViewController:third animated:YES completion:nil];

}
//write this in thirdViewController ViewDidLoad
currentIndex=0;

eachImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:recipeImagedname];

alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];

_second.secCollectionImagesArray=DataArray;

NSLog(@"dataArray:%@",DataArray);

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[swipeLeft setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];

[swipeRight setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

[swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[self.eachImgView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
[self.eachImgView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];


}
-(void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender

{

NSLog(@"swiped :");

NSLog(@"total item is %ld ",(long)DataArray.count);

NSInteger index = currentIndex;


if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)

{

index++;
}

else if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)

{   
index--;

}

if (index > 0 || index < ([DataArray count] - 1))

{
if (index== DataArray.count) {
index=0;

}
currentIndex = index;

[self showImageAtIndex:currentIndex];

}

else

{
if (index < 0) {

index=DataArray.count-1;

currentIndex = index;

[self showImageAtIndex:currentIndex];

}

currentIndex = index;

[self showImageAtIndex:currentIndex];

NSLog(@"Reached the end, swipe in opposite direction");

}

}
```

I hope this code works for you